# most terminal commands are killed

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, apple-silicon, zsh

I have this problem since weeks: my ZSH terminal on start up shows an error and even with most commands (especially if they are sudo).

All results are "killed", sometimes with "Killed: 9". I searched on the web and found out that could be an error with brew. But even following some steps, I cannot uninstall it with terminal command (killed).

I have a MacbookPro M1 PRO (2022). Could you help me to solve this issue?

[image: zsh: killed on terminal just opened]

[image: Even opening terminal on VSCode, end up with same error]

Comment: Did you migrate from an Intel Mac to a Silicon Mac?

Comment: It would help to know which macOS version you are running. If you are fine with doing so, [change your default shell](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/change-the-default-shell-trml113/mac) to bash and see if the problem goes away. You can always change it back.

Comment: This is not zsh getting killed, it's zsh telling you that the program it started was killed with SIGKILL (signal 9). Does it happen only with programs installed through brew or also with programs from `/usr/bin`? Does it happen with an empty or almost empty environment, for example `/usr/bin/env -i /bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/env -i /bin/mkdir /tmp/aaa` ?

Comment: @Allan No, I've only used Silicon Mac
@pwn'cat the last one MacOS Ventura 13.4. I've already tried changing to bash, it kills commands too!
@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I cannot create neither, for example, a dir with `sudo mkdir /tmp/uninstall` to use bash and brew uninstall script found on the web.

Comment: Based on your comments especially the one about finding the script on the web, it may be specific to Intel.  Try installing Rosetta:  `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Comment: @Allan in my case, I just want to use `npm` commands but they don't work. I installed MongoDB and since then, the shell doesn't work. Rosetta2 was already present in my Macbook

Comment: Since this happens on startup, I would debug the zsh startup files, to find out which command exactly causes the error.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Terminal cannot find where **ls** is located.

**Try this:**

whereis ls

[image]

So **ls** is located in bin/ls. So use that complete path[bin/ls].

**Command:** bin/ls

[image]

Try whereis [command_name] and then do the same for every command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342205)